# How to use between?

Tags: differences

Which one is correct?

According to a report by TIME MAGAZINE, there is a 30 percent difference in time for learning between a person who receives help and a person who learns by himself.

According to a report by TIME MAGAZINE, there is a 30 percent difference in time  between a person who receives help to learn and a person who learns by himself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is really correct. What you should say, if you want to be clear, is

> According to a report by TIME MAGAZINE, there is a 30 percent difference in learning time between people who receive help with learning and people who learn by themselves.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. With respect to your sentence, i have a question: why did you write "who receive help with learning"? can we write "who receive help for learning" or " who receive help to learn" as well?

Comment: You are right, "who receive help to learn" is a better form